# Using the same filter for multiple lists in tabs

Tags: angular, filter

I have the following use case in Angular4:
4 lists of data in 4 separate tabs all displayed in (sortable) tables.

Above the tabs, I have a dropdown, where you can select a filter which should filter the list you're currently displaying.

So, in the HTML template, it looks like this for each tab:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of firstTabItems | filterNameFilter: someType | orderBy: sortOrder">
```

Now, when I select a filter from the dropdown, it sorts all four lists. But the user is only viewing one and every time a filter is selected, it filters all four lists again. This is very useless in terms of performance. Basically, I want to have the filter applied only when a tab is selected.

Currently, the filters looks somewhat like this (dumbed down version):

```
@Pipe({
    name : 'filterNameFilter'
})
export class filterNameFilter implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() { }

    transform(items: any[], some_type: string): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.type === some_type);
    }
}
```

Any idea how this could be achieved best?